# Heap buffer overflow with std::deque, portaudio and AddressSanitizer

Tags: c++

I have a music player that generate emulated sound and uses some audio libraries to play it on the PC.

With portaudio library I have a thread that generate the sound, then push it into a dequee, attends that the right time has passed and processes another frame of sounds.

portaudio has a callback function in another thread that at right time, ask for the audio data to use.

In this routine, I get the data from the dequee (that so is used as FIFO) and use them.

The program runs good for some seconds/minutes, then AddressSanitizer catch a  heap-buffer-overflow from the deque.

Here the peaces of code interested.

Routine that generate the sound and push into the dequee:

```
    void AudioDriverPortAudio::play(void* buffer, unsigned long int bufferSize)
{
  unsigned char* memory=(unsigned char*)buffer;

#ifdef XSID_PORTAUDIO_DEBUG
  cout << "AudioDriverPortAudio::play" << endl;
#endif  


  // insert the data at the end of queue
  for (unsigned long int i=0; i<bufferSize; i++) {
    memoryDeque.push_back(*memory);
    memory++;
  }  

  std::cerr << memoryDeque.size() << std::endl;

  int nSize;  // size of one sample
  if (config.precision == AudioConfig::BITS_8) nSize=1;
  else nSize=2;
  nSize*=config.channels;

  // delay needed by actual configuration
  unsigned int delay=1000*(bufferSize/nSize)/config.frequency;

  // compensate for not integer delay to use
  if (memoryDeque.size() > 3*bufferSize) delay++;

  // passed time from last call
  unsigned long int passedTime=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count()-portTime;

  // calculate new delay to use
  signed int newDelay=delay-passedTime;

  if (memoryDeque.size()>bufferSize)
    if (newDelay>0) Pa_Sleep(newDelay);

  if (memoryDeque.size()>2*bufferSize) Pa_StartStream( stream );

  // remember the actual time
  portTime=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();   
}
```

call back function of portaudio:

```
int AudioDriverPortAudio:: portaudio_callback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer, unsigned long framesPerBuffer, 
                               const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo, PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData ) {
#ifdef XSID_PORTAUDIO_DEBUG
  cout << "portaudio_callback " << endl;
#endif
  //unsigned char value;
  unsigned char *out = (unsigned char*)outputBuffer;

  AudioDriverPortAudio* userD=(AudioDriverPortAudio *) userData;

  (void) inputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warning. */
  (void) timeInfo;    /* Prevent unused variable warning. */
  (void) statusFlags; /* Prevent unused variable warning. */
  (void) userData;    /* Prevent unused variable warning. */

  std::cerr << userD->memoryDeque.size() << " " << framesPerBuffer <<  std::endl;

  int nSize;  // size of one sample
  if (userD->lastConfig.precision == AudioConfig::BITS_8) nSize=1;
  else nSize=2;
  nSize*=userD->lastConfig.channels; 

  if (userD->memoryDeque.size()< nSize*framesPerBuffer) {
      std::cerr << "Under-run buffer";
      return 0;
  }    

   for (int i=0; i<nSize*framesPerBuffer; i++) {
      // prevent empty buffer usage  
      if (userD->memoryDeque.empty()) break;  
      *out++=userD->memoryDeque.front();  
      userD->memoryDeque.pop_front();
    }

  return paContinue;
}
```

This is the error:

```
  =================================================================
==136487==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x615000affc80 at pc 0x000000525ed0 bp 0x7fcda22a1bb0 sp 0x7fcda22a1ba0
READ of size 1 at 0x615000affc80 thread T35
76672
    #0 0x525ecf in AudioDriverPortAudio::portaudio_callback(void const*, void*, unsigned long, PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo const*, unsigned long, void*) ../src/audio/AudioDriverPortAudio.cpp:301
    #1 0x7fce04a52d7c  (/lib64/libportaudio.so.2+0x9d7c)
    #2 0x7fce04a54680  (/lib64/libportaudio.so.2+0xb680)
    #3 0x7fce04a5d895  (/lib64/libportaudio.so.2+0x14895)
    #4 0x7fce04a844e1 in start_thread (/lib64/libpthread.so.0+0x94e1)
    #5 0x7fce022b26a2 in clone (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x1016a2)

0x615000affc80 is located 0 bytes to the right of 512-byte region [0x615000affa80,0x615000affc80)
allocated by thread T34 (QThread) here:
    #0 0x7fce04c94a97 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.5+0x10fa97)
    #1 0x51d45e in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<unsigned char>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:114
    #2 0x51d3d6 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<unsigned char> >::allocate(std::allocator<unsigned char>&, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:444
    #3 0x51d2c9 in std::_Deque_base<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_allocate_node() /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_deque.h:620
    #4 0x5227be in void std::deque<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_push_back_aux<unsigned char const&>(unsigned char const&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/deque.tcc:492
    #5 0x5220fb in std::deque<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::push_back(unsigned char const&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_deque.h:1579
    #6 0x525681 in AudioDriverPortAudio::play(void*, unsigned long) ../src/audio/AudioDriverPortAudio.cpp:181
    #7 0x4f9e02 in Player::playAudio(void*, unsigned long) ../src/Player.cpp:620
    #8 0x4fb07e in Player::playJob(QThread*) ../src/Player.cpp:783
    #9 0x4fb29a in PlayerThread::run() ../src/Player.cpp:811
    #10 0x7fce02795e25  (/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5+0xc0e25)

Thread T35 created by T34 (QThread) here:
    #0 0x7fce04bbf955 in pthread_create (/lib64/libasan.so.5+0x3a955)
    #1 0x7fce04a65f47  (/lib64/libportaudio.so.2+0x1cf47)

Thread T34 (QThread) created by T0 here:
    #0 0x7fce04bbf955 in pthread_create (/lib64/libasan.so.5+0x3a955)
    #1 0x7fce0279597e in QThread::start(QThread::Priority) (/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5+0xc097e)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow ../src/audio/AudioDriverPortAudio.cpp:301 in AudioDriverPortAudio::portaudio_callback(void const*, void*, unsigned long, PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo const*, unsigned long, void*)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c2a80157f40: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c2a80157f50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c2a80157f60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c2a80157f70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c2a80157f80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c2a80157f90:[fa]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c2a80157fa0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c2a80157fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c2a80157fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c2a80157fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c2a80157fe0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==136487==ABORTING
```

Essentially it says that this:

*out++=userD->memoryDeque.front();

is giving the buffer overflow over a data created inside:

memoryDeque.push_back(*memory);

So, as I get the data in an input buffer, it is copied (as value, not reference) by pushing into the deque, then that value will be read from dequee again and puts as value into the output pulseaudio library, I did not understant why internally the deque raise the error.

If I did not run with AddressSanitizer, I get that the sounds at some points start to be wrong and after some more times a segmentation fauls is raised.

This approach (with deque and callback function) is uses even with SDL and I get no this kind of problem.

just for reference, the passed and used sound can be of 8 or 16 bits, in mono or stereo way.
it is managed as *unsigned char* so, for example, pulseaudio for a 16 bits-stereo expect 4 values and this is why nSize*framesPerBuffer values are taken from the dequee in the callback function.

Any hint in what is the problem?

Thanks

edit:
forget the definition:

```
std::deque<unsigned char> memoryDeque;
```

edit2:

Play audio (it calls the appropriate library: SDL, PortAudio..):

```
void Player::playAudio(void* pBuf, unsigned long int bufSize)
{
    audioDriverMutex.lock();
    AudioDrivers::getDriver()->play(pBuf,bufSize);
    audioDriverMutex.unlock();
}
```

Play job where sound are generated and then passed to audio library:

```
void Player::playJob(QThread* thread)
{
    while ( playJobActive )
    {
         if ( ++currentBuffer == 2 )
            currentBuffer = 0;
        fillBuffer(pBuffer[currentBuffer],multiBufferSize);
        playAudio(pBuffer[currentBuffer],multiBufferSize);

        if ( endOfSong )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

edit3:

thanks to all.
I make this class and now the problem is gone:

```
#include <deque>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> class safedeque {
  public:  
    void clear()  {
     lock_guard<mutex> lock(q_mutex); 
      memoryDeque.clear();        
    }

    bool empty() {
      lock_guard<mutex> lock(q_mutex);   
      return memoryDeque.empty();
    }    

    std::size_t size() {
      lock_guard<mutex> lock(q_mutex);  
      return memoryDeque.size();
    }    

    void push_back(const T& __x) {
      lock_guard<mutex> lock(q_mutex); 
      memoryDeque.push_back(__x);
    }

    void pop_front() {
      lock_guard<mutex> lock(q_mutex); 
      memoryDeque.pop_front();
    }

    T front() {
      lock_guard<mutex> lock(q_mutex); 
      return memoryDeque.front();       
    }

  private:
    deque<T> memoryDeque;
    mutex q_mutex;
};
```

Comment: Issue is hidden somewhere deeper in call stack and is not visible in included code. Most probably problem is how `Player::playAudio` is used. It fails on `push_back` since this is first time you are referring to that piece of memory.

Comment: The callback is called in a different thread than the one enqueueing the data. You have to add proper locking to ensure only one thread can access the `std::deque` at a time.

Comment: Thanks. So, even if the queue is used as Fifo, one thread push and one thread pop up data already pushed, means that I must apply a mutex to ensure one thread at time is on the queue